# Software updates on a new iPhone

Tags: iphone, software-update

I bought a new iPhone for myself. This is my first iPhone and I like it.

It is now asking me to install a Software Update. What is a Software Update and why is it needed?

Is it okay to install it? I have never used an iPhone before, and I want to make sure I am doing it right.

Comment: An iPhone is basically a computer now. Computers runs software and software could/should/need to be kept up to date and so does phones now. After the phone leaves factory and before you turn it on, a lot of software that comes with the phone has a newer version available and you should take the updates.

Comment: It's a trap to make your phone slower so you buy a new one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is a Software Update and why is it needed?

A software update is released by Apple whenever they have improvements to the core software running on your iPhone. This core software, the operating system, is named iOS and is responsible for general functioning of your iPhone.

A software update can add new software features to your iPhone, fix issues with general functioning of the operating system software and add enhancements that improve the security of the device.

> Is it okay to install it?

It is perfectly normal, even recommend to install a Software Update on your iPhone. Installing a software update most often would require a restart of your iPhone. The restart would be performed automatically as a part of installing the Software Update.

Once started, installing a Software Update can take from a few minutes to around half an hour of time. So make sure not to install it when you would be needing your iPhone for normal usage such as making/receiving phone calls and messages.

> I have never used an iPhone before, and I want to make sure I am doing it right.

A software update should work fine most of the times. You need not worry too much about it. However, it may be a good idea to take a backup of your iPhone.

---

To learn more about iOS, the operating system software running on your iPhone, check this link:

- https://www.apple.com/ios/

To learn more about installing software update on an iPhone, you can read this Apple Support article:

- https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204204

To learn more about the ways to take a backup of your iPhone, you can read this Apple Support article:

- https://support.apple.com/kb/HT203977

Answer (score 2):

### What is a software update

A software update is release by Apple whenever there are improvements made to iOS.

### Why is a software update needed

A software update can fix bugs, glitches and exploits on your firmware. Some updates improve the [security](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201222) of your phone while others may add new features, UI updates or bug fixes. It is highly recommended to update your iPhone to the latest firmware.

### How to update

Updating your iPhone is quite easy and almost nothing can go wrong

#### Updating without a computer

> Plug your device into power and connect to the [Internet with Wi-Fi](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT202639).
>   Go to Settings > General, then tap Software Update.
>
> Tap Download and Install.
>
> To update now, tap Install.
>
> If asked, enter your passcode.

Source: https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204204

#### Updating with a computer

> On a Mac with macOS Catalina 10.15, open Finder. On a Mac with macOS Mojave 10.14 or earlier, or on a PC, open iTunes.
>
> Plug in your iPhone.
>
> Click General or Settings, then click Check for Update.
>
> Click Download and Update.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should install it. Apple is constantly tweaking the iOS operating system and patching possible gaps in the system. Most updates feature security upgrades and new features. it's a regular feature of iPhones. The upgrades will install seamlessly by just clicking to install. Very simple.